# SQS: Know remaining jobs

Tags: node.js, jobs, amazon-sqs, job-scheduling

I'm creating an app that uses a JobQueue using Amazon SQS.

Every time a user logs in, I create a bunch of jobs for that specific user, and I want him to wait until all his jobs have been processed before taking the user to a specific screen.

My problem is that I don't know how to query the queue to see if there are still pending jobs for a specific user, or how is the correct way to implement such solution.

Everything regarding the queue (Job creation and processing is working as expected). But I am missing that final step.

Just for the record:

In my previous implementation I was using Redis + Kue and I had created a key with the user Id and the job count, every time a job was added that job count was incremented, and every time a job finished or failed I decremented that count. But now I want to move away from Redi + Kue and I am not sure how to implement this step.

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon SQS is not the ideal tool for the scenario you describe.** A queueing system is normally used in a "Send and Forget" situation, where the sending system doesn't remain interested in later processing.

You could investigate **Amazon Simple Workflow (SWF)**, which allows work to be monitored as it goes through several processes. Your existing code could mostly be re-used, just with the SWF framework added. Or even power it from Lambda, since you are already using node.js.